# AWS SQS Receive Messages -- How to Know when Queue is Empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I want to get all the messages in the queue to process them. However the property for MaxNumberOfMessages is 10 (based on documentation)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

How can I read in all messages so I can process them? Or how would I know when queue is empty?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you **receive** messages from the queue, they are marked as "in flight."  After you successfully process them, you send a call to the queue to **delete** them.  This call will include IDs of each of the messages.

When the queue is empty, the next read will have an empty `Messages` array.

Usually when I do this I wrap my call to read the queue in a loop (a `while` loop) and only keep processing if I have `Messages` after doing a read.

It shouldn't make any difference if it's a FIFO queue or a standard one.

Comment: I am getting an empty list when there are still messages available. AWS docs state "Amazon SQS never returns more messages than this value [max no. messages] (however, fewer messages might be returned)." Have you experienced this?

Comment: This is incorrect, receiving no messages does not necessarily mean the queue is empty. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the queue is empty you have to verify the total number of messages in the queue is zero. SQS does not provide a single metric for this, rather you have to calculate the sum of three different metrics.

From the docs:

> **To confirm that a queue is empty (AWS CLI, AWS API)**
>
> 1. Stop all producers from sending messages.
> 2. Repeatedly run one of the following commands:
>
>    - AWS CLI: [get-queue-attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/get-queue-attributes.html)
>    - AWS API: [GetQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html)
> 3. Observe the metrics for the following attributes:
>
>    - `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed`
>    - `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible`
>    - `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`
>
>    When all of them are `0` for several minutes, the queue is empty.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/confirm-queue-is-empty.html

Getting an empty response from a `ReceiveMessage` call does NOT necessarily mean the queue is empty. You can have messages in the queue and still receive an empty response if:

1. Messages are delayed - You can set delays on individual messages for standard queues or at the queue level for standard and FIFO queues. During the delay period messages are invisible to consumers.
2. Messages are in-flight - When a consumer receives a message, that message remains in the queue until the consumer deletes it by calling `DeleteMessage`. While the message is in this state it is considered in-flight and is not available for other consumers.
3. Multiple messages have the same message group id in a FIFO queue - When a consumer receives a message from a FIFO queue, no other consumer can receive messages from the same message group. This ensures messages are processed in FIFO order.

By summing the metrics listed above, you can account for all of these scenarios.